# Why does Vagrant cli on Windows (hyper-v) is so slow?

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v

I have installed Vagrant 2.2.16 on Windows 10 (Core i7 3.6 - 16GB memory). Regardless of a command, whatever I type takes too much time to execute. Even a simple `vagrant version` takes time. My Vagrantfile is as below.

```rb
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
    config.vm.box = 'hashicorp/bionic64'
    
    config.vm.provider 'hyperv'
end
```

**Execution time**

- `vagrant ssh` takes more than 2 mins
- `vagrant destroy -f` 3 mins
- `vagrant up` 7-8 mins

I thought maybe memory is the issue so I allocated 2GB to test. It did not make any difference. Is there any way to speed things up? Has anyone experienced similar things on Windows with hyper-v?

Comment: I'm not familiar with vagrant, but such long delays are often caused by network issues. So it tries to connect to something non-essential, for instance to refresh a cache, then only proceeds after that has timed out. Maybe there's more verbose output or logging you can turn on to find out more.

Comment: I enabled the debug mode and can see each step in detail. The log file is humongous! Every step is a PowerShell command with aurgs. Each step has a default timeout. For example, one step is to identify the virtual switch I created in hyperv . The other is about fetching the IP. For obtaining the IP it tried 3 time before successfully assigning one. Pretty much all the steps are very slow.

Comment: Just found 2 open issues related to this [Vagrant CLI on Windows is very slow](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11853) and [vagrant ssh is incredibly slow for Hyper-V provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11956)